# How should I name this function?

Tags: naming-conventions

```
function get_IfUnsetAlsoSet_SomeGlobalVariable() {
    if someGlobalVariable is not set {
        someGlobalVariable = somedata
    }
    return someGlobalVariable 
}
```

Should I give a name like this? -> getSomeGlobalVariable()
How do you name these getset functions?

Comment: I don't, I have properties. I <3 .NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can understand, this smells a bit like the Singleton. So you could use this name:

`GlobalInstance();` or something.

Comment: It is a simple JavaScript/jQuery function which checks if something is in the DOM. If not, the function puts something in the DOM and gets. If it is already set, the function will get it.

Comment: How does the function determine which "something" to put in the DOM? Generally, you should try to minimize the unexpected side effects to your code. The behavior you show would be expected to developers as a singleton, but not necessarily so in a "get" method.

Comment: Aaaah, now I understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

I guess a name like `getSomeGlobalVariable()` should be easy with no confusion.

Basically you do not have to give your complete logic in a method name.

Comment: This method has side effects, naming it get could be confusing if a developer calls it expecting it to simply return the variable.

Comment: @Jim - Yes, so the developer would not care about whether it is being set in the method or not right? He just needs to get the value of the variable I pressume. So I think it should not confuse him.

Comment: The RWTF is that the method has side effects. You need to decide if they matter and if they do you need to document it (in method name or meta) or separate it.

Answer (score -1):

Pardon me if I'm missing something here, But as per your method

```
function get_IfUnsetAlsoSet_SomeGlobalVariable() {
    if someGlobalVariable is not set {
        someGlobalVariable = somedata
    }
    return someGlobalVariable 
}
```

It just do one thing, will set 'somedata' to 'someGlobalVariable'. Personally I think Its not good to use names like 'somedata, someGlobalVariable' instead you may use some meaning full names like 'applicationName, loggedUser etc..'

In your case, basically you are returning a global variable value.

Comment: I'm sure the generic "somedata" names are for example only, not real identifiers used in production code.